# Как дать доступ к read/write uri после закрытия приложения?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Пользователь может выбрать файл с хранилища устройства и открыть его через него же. Но после закрытия приложения все permissions слетают судя по всему, пробовал добавить флаги, возникает новое исключение:
java.lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID 10134 and Uri content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/Билеты матан.docx [user 0]

Открываю файл так:

```
private void openFile(Uri uri) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String mime = getContentResolver().getType(uri);

        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, mime);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Не найдено приложений для открытия этого файла", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, result);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = result.getData();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
//                try {
//                    grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
//                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
//                    // on Kitkat api only 0x3 is allowed (FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
//                    grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
//                } catch (SecurityException e) {
//                    Log.e("", e.toString());
//                }
//                getIntent().addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                pushFile(getFileName(uri), uri);
                uriList.add(uri.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Как мне восстановить permissions после закрытия программы?

Comment: Кажется, тут то, что вам нужно: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69092584/how-do-i-grant-permission-correctly-to-open-files-obtained-through-opendocument. Сам я, правда, не очень понял куда и когда надо применять указанный вызов метода `takePersistableUriPermission()`. Могу лишь  предположить что это надо делать уже после получения Uri файла

Comment: Вот после добавления этой строчки, как раз и возникает другое исключение, которое я в вопросе написал

Comment: Кажется, дело может быть в русских символах и пробелах в файле. Попробуйте выбрать файл с именем без пробелов и с латиницей в названии. В любом случае попробуйте вместо `Uri uri = result.getData()` написать что-то типа `Uri uri = Uri.parse(result.getDataString())`

Comment: К сожалению все равно это исключение выкидывает, не знаю уже что делать, какой день сижу с этой проблемой :/

Comment: Сохраняйте абсолютный путь, и обращайтесь к нему

Comment: Попробуйте запускаемый интент с action `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` сделать вместо `ACTION_VIEW`

Comment: Поясните внятно путь жизни этих uri. Как и откуда они получены, где используются в конечном счёте и какой путь проходят до туда. А то вот этот текст вообще непонятен: _выбрать файл с хранилища устройства и открыть его через него же_

Comment: Нужно описать когда именно возникает ошибка: при выборе файла, при попытке его открыть, после перезагрузки и т.п.

Comment: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT пробовал, просто открывается папка, где находится файл, на который нажали.

Comment: Жизненный путь Uri: пользователь через Intent.createChooser выбирает файл, из onActivityResult берётся Uri и записывается в List<Uri>. В активити создаётся LinearLayout, с названием файла в TextView, onclick для этого LinearLayout указан метод openFile, который открывает файл через Uri. Именно в этой функции выскакивает исключение на строчке startActivity(intent);

Comment: `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` имелось ввиду использовать для первоначального выбора файла, после выбора сразу запросить удержание прав доступа. Если не выходит - прямо в вопросе, подробно по шагам распишите весь путь: этим кодом запрашивается выбор, потом делается то, потом это и т.д. Иначе вам на битву экстрасенсов лучше обратиться.

Comment: Последнее сообщение woesss сработало, поменял на ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT и запросил удержание прав доступа при получения Uri и все заработало. Спасибо всем за помощь!